# Camera2 and MediaRecorder recording blank video only happening on Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge

Tags: android, video, mediarecorder, android-camera2, samsung-galaxy

I have been trying to record video using the camera2 api and MediaRecorder using the same flow as the Camera2Video sample app on googlesamples git repo.  It works great on all devices I have tested except for Galaxy S7 Edge. (Worked on Galaxy S7 and S9 as well as a bunch of other device types). On the S7 Edge it puts out a very small file with audio but no video.

I created an Espresso test that records some video using our app and used Amazon Device Farm to test on the S7 Edge. I also tested with the sample video recording app Camera2Video found at https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video.
I whipped up an espresso test for this sample app too and tried it on Amazon Device Farm and it produced the same results. It worked on S7 but not S7 Edge.

Has anyone with a Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge or Edge+ tried to run the Camera2Video sample app and if so did the output video work as expected?  If anyone has a Galaxy S7 Edge are you please able to test out the sample app and reply if it worked, and if not and you were able to fix it, how you fixed it?

Thank you!

Comment: I think I can report a similiar occurence, also described in my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51079648/android-mediarecorder-video-audio-and-video-track-playing-subsequently) . I can record perfectly on huawei, sony and other android devices, except for samsung devices. The video is playing the recorded audio and when its done, it plays the video frames. What could cause this?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Csharpest!  It was hard to see if this was the issue when using the test devices on Amazon Device Farm as they are all pointing at the wall of their dark little box.  I got my hands on a Galaxy S7 Edge and it looks like the same problem.  There is a solution that someone has found and it works well.

This workaround is the best I have found:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video/issues/24
The user cybaker provides an explanation and sample code.

Comment: Damn, very nice, thanks a lot! so using mp4parser to rewrite the first frame - if its decoding time of this one is enormous - might fix this.