# Android MediaRecorder Video - Audio and Video track playing subsequently

Tags: android, audio, video, xamarin.android, mediarecorder

I came a across a bug, mostly present on samsung devices.
I record a video with media recorder (code shown below). It worked flawlessly, on all devices, but now on some Android Devices the Audio and Video track are separated.

Say I'm capturing 5 sec of Video.
The Video will be 5 sec long, playing the video will play the first frame of the video and the 5 secs of Audio.
After that, the 5 secs of Video are being played.
The default video player shows that the video is over after 5 sec, but in fact its only the audio...

Is there anything newly introduced to 8.0 Oreo, so that I have to adapt my MediaRecorder?

My media recorder setup:

```
private void SetUpMediaRecorder()
        {
            MediaRecorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.Mic);
            MediaRecorder.SetVideoSource(VideoSource.Surface);
            MediaRecorder.SetOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Mpeg4);

            MediaRecorder.SetVideoEncoder(VideoEncoder.H264);
            MediaRecorder.SetAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.Aac);
            MediaRecorder.SetOutputFile(outputURL);
            MediaRecorder.SetVideoSize(1280, 720);

            MediaRecorder.SetVideoFrameRate(30);
            MediaRecorder.SetVideoEncodingBitRate(2000000);
            MediaRecorder.SetMaxDuration(VideoManager.MAX_VIDEODURATION_MS);

            //Set audio bitrate
            int bitDepth = 16;
            int sampleRate = 44100;
            int bitRate = sampleRate * bitDepth;
            MediaRecorder.SetAudioEncodingBitRate(bitRate);
            MediaRecorder.SetAudioSamplingRate(sampleRate);

            int rotation = (int)ThisActivity.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.Rotation;
            int orientation = orientations[rotation];
            MediaRecorder.SetOrientationHint(orientation);
            MediaRecorder.Prepare();
        }
```

EDIT: I'm using the Camera2 API

EDIT2: It seems to be an issue for some samsung devices. The deep sleep will cause the presentation timestamp of the first frame to be too long. Setting the timestamp to 1/30th of a second (if your video was captured at 30fps) will fix this issue.
Here is a corresponding bug thread: 
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video/issues/24

Comment: i am facing the same issue with no luck.

Comment: Hey, look at my newest update of the question, it clears up about the issue. You will have to adjust the timestamp of your first frame to about ~33ms.

Comment: @Cshapest Thank you