# Camera2 MediaRecorder | Audio and Video are recording asynchronously

Tags: java, android, android-camera2, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I am building an app that records video - quite simple. I am using the `Camera2` API along with `MediaRecorder` to achieve this. I have been able to successfully record video, but the sound and video are recording asynchronously.

Let's say I record a 5 second video - the output will be a video file that is 10 seconds in length. The first 5 seconds is a still frame playing the audio, the last 5 seconds will be the video frames without any sound. It is as if the `MediaRecorder` is recording the audio before it even begins to receive video frames.

Device I am using for testing is a Samsung Galaxy 7. I managed to find one person online facing a similar issue with no answers/response: [Android Audio and Video track playing subsequently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51079648/android-mediarecorder-video-audio-and-video-track-playing-subsequently)

How I set up my `MediaRecorder`:

```
private void setUpMediaRecorder() throws IOException {
    final Activity activity = this;
    if (null == activity) {
        print("Null activity!");
        return;
    }

    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    if (nextVideoAbsolutePath == null || nextVideoAbsolutePath.isEmpty()) {
        nextVideoAbsolutePath = getVideoFilePath(this);
    }
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(nextVideoAbsolutePath);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(10000000);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(videoSize.getWidth(), videoSize.getHeight());
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    switch (sensorOrientation) {
        case SENSOR_ORIENTATION_DEFAULT_DEGREES:
            mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
            break;
        case SENSOR_ORIENTATION_INVERSE_DEGREES:
            mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
            break;
    }
    mediaRecorder.prepare();
}
```

My `StartRecording()` function:

```
void startRecording()
{
    //Check the camera and TextureView are ready
    if (null == cameraDevice || !textureView.isAvailable() || null == previewSize) {
        return;
    }

    try {

        //Close the existing capture session used for preview
        closePreviewSession();

        //Set up the MediaRecorder
        setUpMediaRecorder();

        //Compile list of surfaces
        List<Surface> surfaces = new ArrayList<>();
        surfaces.add(previewSurface);
        final Surface recorderSurface = mediaRecorder.getSurface();
        surfaces.add(recorderSurface);

        // Start the capture session
        // Once the session starts, we can update the UI and start recording
        cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(surfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                //Store a reference to the session
                currentCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession;

               //Flag that recording has started
               isRecording = true;
               toggleRecordingButton();

                try {
                    //Initiate requestBuilder
                    captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);

                    //Add the surfaces to the request
                    captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface); 
                    captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(recorderSurface);

                    //Build
                    captureRequest = captureRequestBuilder.build();
                    print("CameraCaptureSession stateCallback onConfigured() - Starting media recorder");

                    //Start recording
                    mediaRecorder.start();

                    //Set repeating request for VIDEO
                    currentCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequest, new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {

                        }
                    }, null);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                print("onConfigureFailed");
                Activity activity = MainActivity.this;
                if (null != activity) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                isRecording = false;
            }
        }, backgroundHandler);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

My `StopRecording()` function:

```
private void stopRecording() {
    // UI
    isRecording = false;
    toggleButtonsWhileRecording();

    // Stop recording
    mediaRecorder.stop();
    mediaRecorder.reset();

    //Reset path
    nextVideoAbsolutePath = null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug limited to certain Samsung Galaxy devices only. See more about this issue and a workaround for detecting the long frame and correcting it after recording:
[Saved video file only has one video frame](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video/issues/24)

In summary, the bug is related to these devices coming out of Deep Sleep. After resetting the phone, problem is solved (but comes back if I let the phone go into Deep Sleep).